# ms access database without installation - vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, jet

Need to create and use ms access database from vba. Access is not installed in my machine. But i am almost sure that it can be used using a jet engine. I have created a database using DAO reference. Sample below.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL
Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library
```

Here is the sample code

```
Dim DBFile As String
Dim ws As Workspace
Dim db As Database
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

DBFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\db_1.accdb"
If Not fso.FileExists(DBFile) Then
    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = ws.CreateDatabase(DBFile, dbLangGeneral)
    Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(DBFile)
End If
```

Now i want to use this using a regular ADODB Connection to create tables using the reference below

```
 C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado28.tlb
 Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
```

I tried below

```
Dim ConStr As String
Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection
   ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\db_1.accdb" & ";Persist Security Info=False"
   Con.Open ConStr, , , 0
   Set Connect = Con
```

But i am getting automation error in con.open.
Is it possible this way? Is it the fact that access is not installed is giving the error? Please suggest any workarounds other than installing Office

Comment: You need this driver to be installed "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" check your odbc manager if this driver is available on your machine.

Comment: I was assuming that windows is preinstalled with it.

Comment: I was able to use "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" instead of "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" and it works fine.